# Error openning a file dialog explorer Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, visual-studio-code

[image: 1º]

[image: 2º to try "Create File"]

I don't know what to do. I proof chmod and chown on /workdir/* and on ~/.config/Code/*

Also put it in launch.json:
"environment": [{"name":"SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN","value":"gen"}],

It occurs when is executed the command:

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open XML"), "/home/XXX", tr("XML Files (*.xml)"));
```

And also happen when is executed the command:

```
char filename[1024];
FILE *f = popen("zenity --file-selection", "r");
fgets(filename, 1024, f);
```

I created a new project and executed only this commands and crash.

On the other hand, if I execute "zenity --file-selection" in the console, it works.

Aaand I proof the code in other computer, and it does work.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    Camera camera;
    camera.show();

    return app.exec();
};
...


//Inside of camera.cpp
    void Camera::FindFile(){
       QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image"), "/home", tr("XML Files (*.xml)"));
       //...
    }
```

Comment: Just *guessing* here, but are you debugging your application? And it crashes? Then the crash may manifest in one of the internal functions and files of the standard library. You don't need to create (and often don't even view) those files. Instead walk up the call-stack until you are in your own code, and the error and reason for the crash should be there somewhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, but not, I review the code and change the command "QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()" to the start of the main and is the same. Is an error of the system. The stack don't show the error because the system try to create a directory /build in who nkows where, and don't have permission.

Comment: ***I review the code and change the command "QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()" to the start of the main*** Have you created your `QApplication` instance before calling this?

Comment: A [mre] would go a long way to be able to help you. And remember to always have error checking.

Comment: Your shown `main` function should not build. The implicit `this` variable is only valid in non-static class or struct member functions.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But is the same. Is something in my system, in other computer it does work, open the dialog and get the path... I dont know if is Ubuntu or VSCode.